# Changing the SQL Server Time & Date Comment Stamp at top of query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2008/12 at the top of my procedures I have the following:

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [Actions].[InsertArea]    Script Date: 16/10/2012 02:56:08 ******/
                                 ----------------------                 ---------- --------
```

It obviously changes depending on the name of the procedure and the date / time it was last modified.

Is there any way to prevent this from changing or to alter it so I have a date created as opposed to a date last modified or am I just stuck with it this way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No, that is the date/time you generated the script, not when the underlying object was modified. See for yourself - right-click a stored procedure, choose Modify. Then do it again a few seconds later. The timestamp has changed. You can always just remove that useless comment before doing anything with the script.

Comment: You can even turn that off in advanced option when generating the script.

Comment: +1 to each of you as thanks guys. I didnt know that it wasnt actually part of the script header. Changed it in advanced options like you said Richard. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you have scripted procedure using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, and script date is the date when create/modify script has been created. This line is added by MSSM.

You can add your own comments with desired dates right before create/alter statement, and they will be saved in database.